# Knowing the two quantities of 'est'

Tags: pronunciation, vowel-quantity

There are several forms of *ĕsse* and *ēsse* (= *edere*) that only differ by the quantity of the initial vowel, perhaps the most common one being *ĕst/ēst*.
How do we know this difference in quantities?

There is a [question on knowing hidden quantities](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1860/79) and the answer gives several mechanisms.
I would be happy to hear how the two quantities are known in this specific case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Servius (4th cent. CE) in his commentary on Virgil [writes](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/2349/5/3096/187-196#3096):

> sānē EDO habet et rēctam, sed antīquam dēclīnātiōnem, ut 'edō edis edit', et anomalam, ut 'edō ēs ēst': quārum secunda et tertia persōnae longae sunt propter differentiam 'sum es est'
>
> (*edo* famously has a regular (but archaic) inflection, as in *edō edis edit,* as well as an irregular one, as in *edō ēs ēst.* In the latter, the 2nd and 3d persons are long for the sake of distinction from *sum es est.*)

Velius Longus (2st cent. CE) [refers to a certain Nisus](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1374/1/15/984-990#15) as advocating spelling a single S in *comēsse* and *cōnsuēsse* on the analogy of *cāsus, causa < cāssus, caussa,* which were no longer spelled or pronounced with a geminate:

> Nimiae rūrsus ēlegantiae sectātōres nōn arbitror imitandōs, tam et sī Nīsus auctor est ut COMESE et CONSVESE per ūnum S scrībāmus et dīcit ratiōnem, quia iuxtā prōductam vōcālem <gemināta> cōnsonāns prōgredī nōn soleat
>
> (On the other hand, I don't think we should take after those who pursue elegance too eagerly, even though Nisus advocates writing *comēsse* and *cōnsuēsse* with a single S, with the reasoning that a double consonant doesn't normally follow after a long vowel)

Donatus' (4th cent.) [commentary](http://hyperdonat.huma-num.fr/editions/html/DonAnd.html#81) on Terence's *Andria* (line 81):

> et prōductē legitur ESSET, ut 'cibum capiat', et correptē, ut alibī
>
> (ESSET is read both with a long vowel, as in '(s)he should eat', and with a short one, as in the other case)